# Blender 2.79 doesn't detect my AMD GPU 270X

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

As described in the title Blender doesn't detect my GPU, it's an *AMD Readeon R9 270x*.

I tried to install an older version of CCC but that didn't work too.

**There is one Strange thing at "OpenGl-Version" in the second column there is written: "Nicht Verfügbar"->not available.**

I attached some screen shots shot at the Amd Catalyst Control Center i hope that will help.

[image]
[image]